# How do I display the contents of a sequential file?

Tags: c++, filestream

I've already written some stuff to file and now I want to read and view the contents on screen. I wrote the function to view but it doesn't display anything. Heres the code for the view function. I was testing to view only  2 variables.Also the display function called at the bottom is from the parent class, which displays all variables from the other classes

```
void ViewAll(string name, Intervention inte)
{
    ifstream clientfile(name, ios::in);
    if (clientfile)
    {
        int hour, min, day, month, yr, snum, age;
        string fname, lname, interNo, problem, clinic, area, ex,  li,                    type,      breed, gender, sname, town, pay;

        while (clientfile && !clientfile.eof())
        { //needed to loop through each record in the file
            clientfile >> interNo;
            clientfile >> clinic;
            clientfile >> lname;
            clientfile >> fname;
            clientfile >> pay;
            clientfile >> snum;
            clientfile >> sname;
            clientfile>> town;
            clientfile >> area;
            clientfile >> ex;
            clientfile >> li;
            clientfile >> type;
            clientfile >> breed;
            clientfile >> gender;
            clientfile >> problem;
            clientfile >> age;
            clientfile >> day;
            clientfile >> month;
            clientfile >> yr;
            clientfile >> hour;
            clientfile >> min;

            if (fname == inte.getClient().getFname())
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        //after record is found, create record
        inte.getClient();
        inte.display();
        system("pause");
    }

    //return inte;
}
```

Comment: You realize you're reading that entire stack of data into local variables, doing *nothing* with them, then firing `inte.display();` and expecting it to do something with... what? (and note `inte` is passed by value, so don't expect the caller to get any changes you may make in here).

Comment: Its  assignment that I'm doing and it is required that I uses classes

Comment: what should I read then? the getters?

Comment: WhozCraig what shud I read then...or how shud I read them

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read into members of inte?  If so you will have to pass inte by reference so you can modify the passed object, then read like

```
clientfile >> inte.interNo;
```

All those local variables you created appear to be useless.

Comment: I am trying to read the members that I have already written to the file which r all apart of inte. The members are apart of other classes that have been in composition in the inte class

Comment: What you did is create local variables with the same name as the members you want to set. That does not work, even if the names are the same. To reference the members of inte you must prefix the names with their object(s).

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, I'd advise structuring the code rather differently. I'd start with overloads of `operator>>` and `operator<<` to read and write data for one `Intervention` respectively:

```
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Intervention &i) { 
        is >> i.interNo;
        is >> i.clinic;
        is >> i.lname;
        is >> i.fname;

        // ...

        is >> i.min;
        return is;
}
```

...and correspondingly `operator<<`:

```
std::ostream &operator>>(std::ostream &os, Intervention const &i) { 
        os << i.interNo;
        os << i.clinic;
        os << i.lname;
        os << i.fname;

        // ...

        os << i.min;
        return os;
}
```

With those in place, we can display all the records from a file with a simple call to `std::copy` using `istream_iterator` and `ostream_iterator`:

```
std::ifstream in(name);

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Intervention>(in),
          std::istream_iterator<Intervention>(),
          std::ostream_iterator<Intervention>(std::cout, "\n"));
```

This eliminates some problems your code included, such as trying to use:

```
while (clientfile && !clientfile.eof())
```

Code like `while (!somefile.eof())` is nearly a guaranteed bug ("nearly" only because it's possible to write *other* code along with it that will cover up for the fact that this code doesn't and can't work correctly).

Comment: thanks man for ur help..much appreciated...one ques though..should I add the overloads to my class or my driver/main?